# Trying to search for an element in a listed tuple that has a new datatype

Tags: haskell

I've created a new datatype `Board`:

```
data Board a = Grid [(Position, Maybe a)]
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

where `Position` is its own datatype:

```
data Position = NW | N | NE | W | M | E | SW | S | SE
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

Now I'm trying to create a function `label`, that takes a `Position` and `Board` and returns the label at the given position (wrapped using `Just`) or `Nothing` if the given position is empty.

I was thinking of implementing a new function Search to do this.

```
search :: (Eq a) => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b
search _ [] = Nothing
search x ((a,b):xs) = if x == a then Just b else search x xs
```

But I don't know how to pass in the List `[(a,b)]` from my `Board` input. I tried:

```
label :: Position -> Board a -> Maybe a
label p b = Search p b
```

and got the error:

```
    * Couldn't match expected type: [(Position, a)]
                  with actual type: Board a
    * In the second argument of `lookup', namely `b'
      In the expression: lookup p b
      In an equation for `label': label p b = lookup p b
    * Relevant bindings include
        b :: Board a (bound at A6.hs:21:9)
        label :: Position -> Board a -> Maybe a (bound at A6.hs:21:1)
```

Perhaps there's an easier way to go about this, but this is the only way I could think of.

([Aplet123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5923139/aplet123) pointed out a mistake, since updated and updated the error produced)

Comment: Just FYI, your `search` function is just the [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup) function. Also, `search (p, b)` is passing the tuple `(p, b)` to `search`, **not** passing the arguments `p` and `b`.

Comment: @Aplet123 Ahh thank you, always making silly mistakes like that in Haskell :/ I've updated my post but still getting an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into your data type under the wraps to find the actual datum there,

```
label :: Position -> Board a -> Maybe a
label p (Grid b) = search p b
--       ^^^^
```

Function names in Haskell must not be capitalized. That is reserved for types and data constructors.

The above will give you another type error but you'll be able to tweak it, I believe, to get it fixed. For starters, enter the definition without the type signature, to see what type is inferred for it.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I got the error saying it returned 'Maybe (Maybe a)' instead of just 'Maybe a', I modified my search function to not return 'Maybe b', but just 'b' instead. And that seems to be working! Also I believe you mean where I capatlised Search here "label p b = Search p b". I didn't actually have that capatalised in my code thankfully, when I typed up this post I rewrote the function and made it 'S' by mistake.

Comment: Also is there any sources you'd recommend that have examples of datatypes in Haskell. I was reading through one book but it didn't seem to have examples like mine. (It probably did and I just didn't understand them)

Comment: you're welcome. if the answer has helped you, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the big empty V sign next to it. you can read some tutorials, e.g. search for "learn you a Haskell for great good". also see Getting Started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info).