# Swapping two elements in a list of tuples

Tags: haskell

*(this is a followup question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70104854/trying-to-search-for-an-element-in-a-listed-tuple-that-has-a-new-datatype), which has the missing  definitions)*

Trying to create a function that can swap two elements in a list of tuples.
for example if I had:

```
[(NW, Just 1),(N, Just 2),(NE, Just 3),(W, Just 4),(M, Just 5),
 (E, Just 6),(SW, Just 7),(S, Just 8),(SE, Nothing)]
```

and I wanted to swap the second elements of S and SE to get

```
[(NW, Just 1),(N, Just 2),(NE, Just 3),(W, Just 4),(M, Just 5),
 (E, Just 6),(SW, Just 7),(S, Nothing),(SE, Just 8)]
```

How would I go about doing this? I tried creating a function `swapper`,

```
swapper :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> b -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
swapper x y z ((a,b):xs) | x == a = ((a,z):xs)
                         | z == b = ((a,y):xs)
                         | otherwise = swapper x y z xs
```

But this returns

```
[(S,Nothing),(SE,Nothing)]
```

I can see that I'm not storing the initial tuples or looping after finding one of my goal states. However I'm not sure how to go about doing this in Haskell.

To give a little more context in case required, the four inputs of the function are

```
(swapper p (label p (Grid b)) (Nothing) b)
```

where

```
p = position I want to move to the Nothing space -- (S -> SE)
label p (Grid b) = returns current label of p -- (S = Just 8)
Nothing = passing in Nothing because I was getting errors 
          when trying to do z == Nothing
b = current board -- ([(NW, Just 1),(N, Just 2),(NE, Just 3),
                  --   (W, Just 4),(M, Just 5),(E, Just 6),
                  --   (SW, Just 7),(S, Just 8),(SE, Nothing)])
```

Comment: To me, it's unclear what the logic is. You write _if [...] I wanted to swap the second elements of S and SE_, and you've given an example where those elments are the last two. That is too specific. You should explain what you want to do in more general terms, imho.

Comment: @Enlico Sorry for the bad explanation! The idea behind the code is a 3x3 sliding puzzle game. So you can think of the positions as the 9 pieces, where one will always be blank. I already wrote the part that checks if the piece can move (I.e its next to the empty piece). So the two elements of the tuple are (Position, maybe Label). I wanted to keep the ordering of Positions constant, hence wanted to move the Label. I hope that exapnds on my question and gives you a better idea!

Answer (score 3):

How about creating a function that can split a list into predecessors, matching element and successors?

```
splitOn :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], Maybe a, [a])
splitOn predicate xs =
  case break predicate xs of
    (us, []) -> (us, Nothing, [])
    (us, (m:vs)) -> (us, Just m, vs)

> splitOn (== 3) [1..5]
([1,2],Just 3,[4,5])
> splitOn (== 7) [1..5]
([1,2,3,4,5],Nothing,[])
```

Then you can split, swap and recombine:

```
import Data.Maybe (maybeToList)

swap :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
swap a b xs = 
  let (us, m, xs') = splitOn predicate xs
      (vs, n, ws) = splitOn predicate xs'
  in us ++ (maybeToList n) ++ vs ++ (maybeToList m) ++ ws
  where
    predicate x = x == a || x == b

> swap 3 4 [1..5]
[1,2,4,3,5]
> swap 7 4 [1..5]
[1,2,3,5,4]
```

Not that this version assumes that an element is contained in the list at most once.

An updated version which swaps the first element (if the element is contained more than once) is

```
swap' :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a] -> [a]
swap' a b xs = 
  let (us, m, xs') = splitOn isFirst xs
      (vs, n, ws) = case m of
        Nothing -> (xs', Nothing, [])
        Just m' -> splitOn (== (other m')) xs'
  in us ++ (maybeToList n) ++ vs ++ (maybeToList m) ++ ws
  where
    isFirst x = x == a || x == b
    other x = if x == a then b else a

> swap' 3 4 (3:[1..5])
[4,1,2,3,3,5]
> swap' 7 4 (3:[1..5])
[3,1,2,3,5,4]
> swap' 3 3 (3:[1..5])
[3,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: @WillNess Do you have a hint? I am not really happy about my updated version.

Comment: I just meant  directly using the `(== a)` in the first call, and `(== b)` in the second, simply.

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote, you don't want return `((a,z):xs)` if `x==a`. You want to process the rest of the list: `((a,z):swapper x y z xs)`. Same with `z==b`. Then the algorithm ended with an error: `Non-exhaustive patterned in function swapper`.
So I added pattern for empty list: `swapper x y z [] = []`. Then the `swapper` returned only part of the list. So I added `(a,b):` also before the `swapper` to the clause `otherwise`.

Now your algorithm looks like this:

```
swapper :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> b -> [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
swapper x y z ((a,b):xs) | x == a = ((a,z):swapper x y z xs)
                         | z == b = ((a,y):swapper x y z xs)
                         | otherwise = (a,b):swapper x y z xs
swapper x y z [] = []
```

And returns the list as you expected:

```
[(NW,Just 1),(N,Just 2),(NE,Just 3),(W,Just 4),
 (M,Just 5),(E,Just 6),(SW,Just 7),(S,Nothing),(SE,Just 8)]
```

I assume that we speak about something like this:
[image: Wood Block Puzzle - Sliding Jigsaw 9]

Comment: How about `swapper S (Just 8) Nothing [(NW, Nothing),(S, Just 8),(SE, Nothing)] == [(NW,Just 8),(S,Nothing),(SE,Just 8)]`? That is the `Nothing` in the first tuple got replace. Seems wrong to me, but the question is vague.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Our  `swapper S (Just 8) Nothing b` says: 1) if `S` is the first part of tuple then return `(S,Nothing):xs`. 2) if `Nothing` is the second part of a tuple (and first is not `S`) then return `(???,(Just 8)):xs`. 3) let the tuple as is in other cases. So `NW` and `SE` are the second rule's work because second part of the tuples is Nothing.

Comment: I must admit that I have a hard time following the question and the `swapper` implementation. Thank you for your explanation which made it a little bit better for me. However I am still worried that touching more than two elements is not wanted, since the title says "Swapping two ..." yet in this case three are touched. If I understand you correctly this is not wrong but a miss use of `swapper` then? But then I wonder what the list must look like to work correctly with `swapper`.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Sorry, I answered you as if you were Jaffa (asker). I wonder about the real-world scenario behind this piece of code. So It only Jaffa knows. I assumed the unique second parts are only permutating.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Sorry for not being clear with my question, struggle to get my point across. David was correct in that I was trying to create a sliding puzzle game, where only one piece can be empty (Nothing) at once. The tuple works as a (Position, maybe Label). (See my response to Enlico above)

Comment: @DavidLukas Thank you! that's the solution I was looking for. You assumed correct with the sliding puzzle, should have been clearer about that. Thought I could break it down to just the function I wanted but probably a bad idea.